# Relationship between Optical Power output and luminous intensity

Tags: optics, fiber-optics, light-emitting-diodes

I have an LED with the following specification which I'm using for oxygen saturation measurements. Here the optical output power is given as >1.2mW for RED LED and >0.5mW for IR LED. How to convert optical output power into relative luminous intensity (mcd)?

[image]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Do you want to know the radiant flux of the white LED or do you want to know the luminous flux of the red LED. The IR LED doesn't have a luminous flux because IR light isn't visible.

Comment: In addition, luminous _intensity_ (units of candela, or in your case millicandela) is actually flux _per solid angle_, and your data sheet only gives 'total' flux/power values.  So to calculate intensity, you would also need a graph of where that flux goes vs angle, as well as an angle from the LED you wish to get intensity for.  Perhaps you need the solid angle subtended by the entrance to your fiber?